# ruby simple race condition question

Tags: ruby, multithreading, race-condition

I came across this example of a race condition:

```
def inc(n)
  n + 1
end

sum = 0

threads = (1..10).map do
  Thread.new do
    10_000.times do
      sum = inc(sum)
    end
  end
end

threads.each(&:join)
p sum
```

Threads run in pararell and there's a chance that while one thread reads sum's value, another one completes incrementing it, but the former is about to finish its own incrementing with the old value, and as a result sum won't change.

But I was wondering, why when I replace the line 'sum = inc(sum)' to 'sum += 1', the output appears to be always correct.

Why is that?

Is it because the overhead of calling a method is so huge compared to just doing a variable assignment and thus some threads 'get out of sync' causing the output to be incorrect?

I assume, that even with a straight sum += 1 I would still be able to observe a race condition, but only if I had been doing a much longer summing loop, etc.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it because the overhead of calling a method is so huge compared to just doing a variable assignment and thus some threads 'get out of sync' causing the output to be incorrect?

Yes.  To verify it, just increase your counter and run several tests.  I increased it to `100_000.times` and here are the results:

```
$ seq 5 | xargs -L 1 ruby a.rb 100000
451167
472581
464413
442191
454204
```

Well, it doesn't seem that nice, does it?

So, yes, increment is not atomic in Ruby (and I doubt that there's a lot of languages where it is).  But there are helper classes to implement such behavior; for example, [this one](https://github.com/headius/ruby-atomic).